# How can I automatically adjust colors between screen and print?

Tags: printer

I have a Kyocera Ecosys p5021cdw color laser printer. When I print blue, it comes out as purple.

For example, I have a blue box in e.g., Inkscape with color RGB 0/0/255 (CMYK 100/100/0/0), which looks blue as it can be on the screen but comes out purple on paper. Now I found that I get a still blue looking box on the screen when I change the blue in Inkscape to RGB 0/77/255 (CMYK 100/70/0/0) and that makes for a blue box in print as well. (I didn't go through [intense calibration](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74365/how-configure-color-in-indesign-for-a-specific-printer) as this is only for home use and if blue looks like blue and not like purple, that's close enough or me.)

Since it's a bit inconvenient to manually adjust my blues before printing, I was wondering if there was an easier way.

I tried to point CUPS to the `.ppd` and `.icm` files that came with the printer (one after the other), but that didn't change the results: blue came out as purple.

How can I configure my printer to always automatically adjust for the color differences between screen and paper?

Comment: That sounds like most likely there's something wrong in how the data is prepared for the printer. Can you check which printer driver specifically you are currently using?